# Error when converting an XSD to its classes with JAXB

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

This is the first time I've ever tried to use JAXB for anything at all and I'm running into a problem.

I'm trying to use JAXB's XJC tool to convert an XSD file into Java class files when I get this error:

```
parsing a schema...  
[ERROR] The prefix "msdata" for attribute "msdata:ColumnName" associated with an element type "xs:simpleContent" is not bound.  
line 10 of file:/home/jeremy/TypeDefs.xsd
Failed to parse a schema.
```

Line 10 in the schema file reads:

```
<xs:simpleContent msdata:ColumnName="paramText" msdata:Ordinal="1">
```

and you can see the whole thing [here](http://maps.trimet.org/maps/model/xml/TypeDefs.xsd).

**edit**: It turns out the XSD file was missing the namespace declaration for msdata. Simply adding `xmlns:msdata="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/07/msdata.xsd"` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have the `msdata` namespace prefix mapped. Like

```
<xs:schema targetNamespace="http://maps.trimet.org/maps/model/xml" 
    xmlns="http://maps.trimet.org/maps/model/xml"
    ....
    xmlns:msdata="http://yournamespace.com/foo">
```

Comment: Thanks, I figured this out about the same time you answered, but you were right, so... ACCEPTED!